# Powershell dot notation vs select-object

Tags: powershell, syntax, properties

Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between dot notation and select-object in Powershell?
How these two methods of accessing properties differ internally?

I've noticed that running `(ls).name` gives basically the same results as `ls | select-object name` however running `ls | select-object name | export-csv foo.csv` gives me proper csv file while trying `(ls).name | export-csv foo.csv` gives me the file with length.
In both cases gettype() returns Object[]

Answer (score 6):

The `select-object` cmdlet wraps the result in a new object. To see the differences (look at the Type) use the `get-member` cmdlet.

```
(ls).Name | get-member
```

and

```
ls | select-object Name | get-member
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the difference now. It seems that `(ls).name` is equal to the `ls | select-object -expandproperty name`. Is it possible to use dot notation without expanding property?

Comment: No. Dot notation is reading the value of the property you specify, just like `ls | % { $_.name }` would, so it you want it as a property in a New Object, you have to use `Select-Object` or `New-Object` (in a foreach-loop).